# Which gives the most realistic pictures, Mirror, camera or their combination?

Tags: optics, reflection, camera

By googling, I have found several different opinions about how to take one's own facial images more realistically:

- Some said photos taken by cameras (smartphone's cameras, if specific) are more objective than images from flat mirrors, because it is close to what others see myself.
- some said the opposite because of distortion of camera lens.
- some suggested it is better to take pictures of the images from an mirror by a camera.

I wonder which way gives the most realistic images of one's own face?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about realism of images and not physics.

Answer (score 1):

If there is "distortion of camera lens" it's going to be there with or without the mirror.  All the mirror is going to do for you is swap your left/right sides, and photograph any dirt/blemishes/defects the mirror itself introduces.

Comment: Thanks. I mainly concern about shape, not dirt/blemishes

Comment: Unless your mirror cost thousands or millions of dollars, it's not going to correct any distortions created by the camera lens -- it will just introduce new ones.

Comment: for phone cameras held by hand, is the distance in self taken pictures too small for having big distortion? So when using a mirror, it extends the distance to lessen distortion of camera?